# Can I create two kinds of helperText in MUI React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to both MUI and React, but in an effort to keep smaller stuff off our overworked devs' plates, I'm tackling a couple of things. One of those is: I'm attempting to retroactively add some descriptive helperText to a few fields. At present, we're already set up for error helperText; I need to be able to do this without taking away that capability.

Here's our current FormInputText.tsx:

```
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { FormInputProps } from "./FormInputProps";
import { FormHelperText } from "@mui/material";

export const FormInputText = ({
  name,
  control,
  label,
  required = false,
  type = "text",
  disabled = false,
  big = false,
  score = false,
}: FormInputProps) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({
        field: { onChange, value },
        fieldState: { error },
        formState,
      }) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            style={{ marginBottom: "25px" }}
            helperText={error ? error.message : null}
            size={!big ? "small" : "medium"}
            error={!!error}
            onChange={onChange}
            fullWidth
            label={label}
            variant="outlined"
            value={value}
            required={required}
            type={type}
            disabled={disabled}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

How can I modify this to allow non-error-type helperText?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add non-error-type helper text to your FormInputText component, you can use **FormHelperText** from `Material-Ui` here is your modified code

```
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { FormInputProps } from "./FormInputProps";
import { FormHelperText } from "@mui/material";

export const FormInputText = ({
  name,
  control,
  label,
  required = false,
  type = "text",
  disabled = false,
  big = false,
  score = false,
  helperText, // new prop for non-error helper text
}: FormInputProps) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({
        field: { onChange, value },
        fieldState: { error },
        formState,
      }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <TextField
              style={{ marginBottom: "25px" }}
              helperText={error ? error.message : helperText} // use new prop for helper text
              size={!big ? "small" : "medium"}
              error={!!error}
              onChange={onChange}
              fullWidth
              label={label}
              variant="outlined"
              value={value}
              required={required}
              type={type}
              disabled={disabled}
            />
            // If you want to display error message as well
            {error && (
              <FormHelperText error>
                {error.message}
              </FormHelperText>
            )}
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

As you can see in this modificated code, I added a new prop helperText to the component. Now, you can pass the non-error helper text when using the FormInputText component. If the error is present, it will display the error message otherwise, it will display the helperText prop.

Comment: I think that did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you show helperText only if error is true, and you can pass one more prop to `FormInputText` called `helperText = ""` (by default), and replace your code from `helperText={error ? error.message : null}` to `helperText={error ? error.message : helperText}`. So now if you pass helperText prop to `FormInputText`, and error is false, it will display it.